# Drag and Drop with databinding

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm

Currently I am doing my drag and drop event in following way :
In `xaml` I have

```
        AllowDrop="True"
        PreviewDragOver="DragOver"
        PreviewDrop="Drop"
```

And in code behind I have :

```
 private void DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ((LogParserViewModel) this.DataContext).DragOver(e);
        }

        private void Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ((LogParserViewModel)this.DataContext).Drop(e);
        }
```

But I want to change it to proper MVVM way , how I can bind following events to `RelayCommand` , that I will get there all needed `DragEventArgs`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the EventCommander as shown here:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchII.aspx.